# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET appears every time I want to access hasMany collection in my Model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I got a weird problem I can't handle with. I got a simple Shop Application in Laravel and Vue/Vuex for frontend.

My `Order` model has a `hasMany` relationship:

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
}
```

and it's fine.

I'm making a `GET /orders/` request from vuex action to fetch `orders` from Laravel. This is my `OrderController@index` action:

```
// Return JSON response if wantsJson otherwise just show View.
if ($this->request->wantsJson()) {
    $orders = Order::with(['client', 'items'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    return response()->json($orders);
}

return view('panel.orders.index');
```

As we can see below it worked as excepted - returned JSON response with `orders`.

[image: successfully fetch orders]

Each `order` has a two `$appends` fields: `total_net` & `total_net_after_discounts` and its methods: `getTotalNetAttribute()` & `getTotalNetAfterDiscountsAttribute()`.

For `$appends` calculations I need an `items` relationship items. So inside `getTotalNetAttribute()` method I'm trying to get a relation items:

```
public function getTotalNetAttribute()
{
    $items = $this->items;
}
```

When I just add `$this->items` into method I got a response: **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**. My whole response is broken after that. I can't even log it:

```
public function getTotalNetAttribute()
{
    logger($this->items); // it just breaking up my response: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
}
```

[image]

Another weird thing is that it's working in `tinker`. I mean I can use `$this->items`, sum their prices and get `$order->total_net` value with no problems.

**EDIT:**
I found a workaround:

```
public function getNetPriceAttribute()
{
    $orderItems = $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class)->get();

    return $orderItems->sum(function ($item) {
        return $item->net_price;
    });
}
```

Comment: what about `return $this->items()->sum('net_price');`?

Comment: Unfortunately 'net_price' is not a column, it's an $append field.

Comment: in your workaround method `getNetPriceAttribute()`, `return $item->net_price;` is not referring to a db column on the items table?  your snake case there is throwing me off then.